# Wallpaper keeps changing to a color-only background

Tags: desktop-background

I just recently switched to Ubuntu from XP. Everything was working fine until recently. I had an xPlanetFX background and then one day it disappeared and only a color background was visible. I tried reloading the background, but it did nothing.

Then, I tried using one of the default backgrounds, but it kept changing back to a color background.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?